# float left gives unwanted padding at the right

Tags: html, css

Hello everytime I use a float left somewhere in that page I get a weird padding at the right. with normal browsers its OK but with viewing on a iPad it's kinda ugly because I get a kind of padding of like 1 cm at the right.. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You sould provide an example

Comment: Are you sure you're not inheriting some kind of padding (or margin) on the element? Have you tried explicitly setting it to 0?

Comment: I do use a reset for my css. you can see a example if you go to www dot bellataxihaarlem dot nl

Comment: There is some badly formed HTML on this page which may or may not be a contributory factor to your problem. with the section "acties" you have a UL containing LI elements. You also have DIV elements placed inbetween the LI elements - this isn't correct html. You can have DIVS within LI elements but not inbetween them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for ipad specific CSS

```
    @media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
         /* For general iPad layouts */
                }

    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)   and (orientation:portrait) {
         /* For portrait layouts only */
          }

       @media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
       /* For landscape layouts only */
          }
```

EDIT :

```
    <!--Target iPad-->
     <link href="ipad.css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)" type="text/css" />
    <!--Target iPhone 3GS> -->
    <link href="iphone.css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and  (max-device-width: 480px)" type="text/css" />
     <!--Target iPhone 4-->
     <link href="retnia.css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-device-width: 480px)" type="text/css" />
```

the jquery

```
    if(navigator.platform == 'iPad' || navigator.platform == 'iPhone' || navigator.platform == 'iPod')
   {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('header').css('top', $(this).scrollTop());
    });

   };
```

and use your special css file for your ipad when you target it for IPAD  , in the code above your file will be 'ipad.css'